# Canvas does not draw in Custom View

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I created a Custom View CircleView like this:

```
public class CircleView extends LinearLayout {

    Paint paint1;
    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }   
    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public void init() {
        paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(Color.RED); 
    }       
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas);         
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 25, paint1);
        this.draw(canvas);  
    }
}
```

Then I included it on my Activity's layout root `<RelativeLayout>`:

```
  <com.turkidroid.test.CircleView
      android:id="@+id/circle_view"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />
```

However, nothing was drawn!

- Am I implementing the Custom View right?
- Or is it how I used the Custom View?

Some Info:

- Both CircleView and MyActivity are in the same package: `com.turkidroid.test`.
- In `onDraw()` method, I tried including `super.onDraw()` and commenting it.
- I know I can draw a circle with much simpler approaches but my CircleView *will* contain more than drawing a circle. I need to make it a Custom View.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your `onDraw` method is never called, you need to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` on the constructor of your Custom View in order to get `onDraw` actually called.

As stated on Android SDK:

> If this view doesn't do any drawing on its own, set this flag to allow
> further optimizations. By default, this flag is not set on View, but
> could be set on some View subclasses such as `ViewGroup`. Typically, if
> you override `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` you should clear this
> flag.

Comment: It throws `java.lang.StackOverflowError` after I added the method to the constructors! Any ideas?

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm after I `un-commented super.onDraw()` from my code. Thanks!

Comment: i'm not sure what it was, my super.ondraw call was missing and the above flag also was set to default, but after putting in both magic happened!! ^_^

Comment: I wish to give more than a single up vote... this is a terrible issue for custom views...

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `this.draw()` method?

This should work definitively:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);         
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 25, paint1);
    //this.draw(canvas);  where is this method?
}
```

Comment: `this.draw()` is the [`View.draw()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method. Still didn't work!

Comment: After I added `setWillNotDraw(false)` to the constructors, it DOES work! I don't know why!

Comment: If you need a custom view, you should always extend from View and not from LinearLayout unless you really need the specific behavior, too.