# Canvas is not drawing in custom Android View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have created my custom `View` in Android and trying to draw a circle in that but nothing is drawing but with no errors.
Here is my code

```
public class ColorOptionsView extends RelativeLayout {
    private View mValue;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private Paint paint;
    String cirlceText;
    int circleColor,circleTextColor;
    float circleTextSize;


    public ColorOptionsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ColorOptionsView, 0, 0);
        try {
            cirlceText = a.getString(R.styleable.ColorOptionsView_circleText);
            circleColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ColorOptionsView_circleColor, 0);
            circleTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ColorOptionsView_circleTextColor, 0);
            circleTextSize = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ColorOptionsView_circleTextSize,20);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

    }



    public void setCirlceText(String cirlceText) {
        this.cirlceText = cirlceText;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }



    public void setCircleColor(int circleColor) {
        this.circleColor = circleColor;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }



    public void setCircleTextColor(int circleTextColor) {
        this.circleTextColor = circleTextColor;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }



    public void setCircleTextSize(float circleTextSize) {
        this.circleTextSize = circleTextSize;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(circleColor);
        int centerX = this.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
        int centerY = this.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
        int raduis = 150;
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX,centerY,raduis,paint);

        paint.setColor(circleTextColor);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        canvas.drawText(cirlceText,centerX,centerY,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0,100,100,0,paint);
    }
```

I am not getting where I went wrong. Devs check it and help me out.

Comment: Your default colors are both transparent. Are you setting other colors on the `View` somewhere? Oh, and you're extending a `ViewGroup`, which isn't going to draw itself by default. Either extend a regular `View`, or call `setWillNotDraw(false)` in the constructor.

Comment: A similar problem here. Check if this solution helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12261790/6172439

Comment: @DarshanMiskin i have implemented all those solutions but no use

Comment: @MikeM. I tried by extending regular View and it worked like a charm.

Comment: did you check if `onDraw` is ever called?